# Passing reference to member to constructor of base class

Tags: c++

I have created a dependency injection with A depending on IB a B1 implementing IB. For a very specific case I would like to create a class C : A that wouldn't expose dependency injection. I want:

1. C to construct the dependency and pass it to it's base class A elegantly handling lifetime of dependency
2. C to effortlessly expose A's public methods to user

```
class IB
{
    public:
        virtual void InterfaceCall() = 0;
        /* ... */
}

class B1 : IB
{
    public:
        void IntefaceCall();
        /* ... */
}

class A
{
    public:
        A(IB& ib);
}

// for a specific case I would like to use class A and all it's logic and public methods, but remove dependency injection
class C : A
{
    B1 b1;
    public:
        C()
        : A(b1)
        , b1() // the order of initialization list is determined by standard
        {}
}
```

Is this even possible or do I need to drop one of my requirements for C?

Comment: When `C`'s constructor is invoked, the object `b1` is not constructed yet. However, you can still pass its address (or reference). The correctness of your code depends whether the `A`'s constructor uses `ib` or not (it should not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is well-formed **if the `A` constructor doesn't actually access any members using the reference.**

Edit: **`A`'s destructor must not use any members of the reference either**, as the values will be destructed in reverse order (first `b1` and then the inherited `A`).

You can ensure that this is well-formed without knowledge of how the `A` constructors and/or destructor might use the reference by controlling the order of initialization.  You can do this by inheriting another type that provides the `b1` member before inheriting from `A`.

Here is the type we will inherit from:

```
// C++03 version
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct member
{
    T value;
};

// C++11 version
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct member
{
    T value;

    template <typename... Args>
    member(Args && ...a) : value{std::forward<Args>(a)...} { }
};
```

Then we'll have `C` inherit it privately, before inheriting `A`:

```
class IB
{
    public:
        virtual void InterfaceCall() = 0;
};

class B1 : public IB
{
    public:
        B1() { std::cout << "constructed B1 " << static_cast<void *>(this) << '\n'; }

        virtual void InterfaceCall() { }
};

class A
{
    public:
        A(IB & ib) { std::cout << "constructed A with B1 " << static_cast<void *>(&ib) << '\n'; }
};

class C : private member<B1>, public A
{
    // For convenience, if you need to use the B1 object in C.  If not, you
    // can omit this reference.    
    B1 & b1;

    public:
        C() :
            member<B1>(), // Implied
            A(member<B1>::value),
            b1(member<B1>::value) { }
};
```

Sample output demonstrating that the initialization order is correct:

```
constructed B1 0x7ffe691b9710
constructed A with B1 0x7ffe691b9710
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc72da10406b8b71))

---

Note that the second parameter of the `member` template is a tag that will allow you to use this technique to control initialization order for multiple members of the same type, should you need to.  For example, `class foo : member<B1, TagA>, member<B1, TagB>`.